# I'm having some undefined references and can't figure out why

Tags: arduino-nano

Try verifying the code to see the errors.  This is on a arduino nano with a 328 processor.  I put the necessary library in the code.
[Pastebin for code](http://pastebin.com/TbTJQfBn)

```
 #ifndef Pushbutton_h 
#define Pushbutton_h 


#include <Arduino.h> 


#define PULL_UP_DISABLED    0 
#define PULL_UP_ENABLED     1 


#define DEFAULT_STATE_LOW   0 
#define DEFAULT_STATE_HIGH  1 


/*! \brief The pin used for the button on the 
 * [Zumo Shield for Arduino](http://www.pololu.com/product/2504). 
 * 
 * This does not really belong here in this general pushbutton library and will 
 * probably be removed in the future. */ 
#define ZUMO_BUTTON 12 


class PushbuttonStateMachine 
{ 
public: 
  PushbuttonStateMachine(); 
  bool getSingleDebouncedRisingEdge(bool value); 
private: 
  uint8_t state; 
  uint16_t prevTimeMillis; 
}; 


class PushbuttonBase 
{ 
public: 


  PushbuttonBase(); 


  // wait for button to be pressed, released, or pressed and released 
  void waitForPress(); 
  void waitForRelease(); 
  void waitForButton(); 


  // more complex functions that return true once for each button transition 
  // from released to pressed or pressed to released 
  bool getSingleDebouncedPress(); 
  bool getSingleDebouncedRelease(); 

  // indicates whether button is currently pressed 
  bool isPressed(); 


  // Initializes I/O pin for use as button input. 
  // This gets called automatically so normally you will not need to call this, 
  // but it might be useful if the pin for the button is in the wrong state. 
  virtual void init2() = 0; 


protected: 


  virtual bool _isPressed() = 0; 


private: 


  PushbuttonStateMachine pressState; 
  PushbuttonStateMachine releaseState; 
  bool initialized; 


  // TODO: move all this init stuff down into Pushbutton 
  inline void init() 
  { 
    if (!initialized) 
    { 
      initialized = true; 
      init2(); 
    } 
  } 
}; 


/* \class Pushbutton Pushbutton.h 
 * \brief Interface with pushbuttons on dedicated pins. 
 * 
 */ 
class Pushbutton : public PushbuttonBase 
{ 
public: 


  // constructor; takes arguments specifying whether to enable internal pull-up 
  // and the default state of the pin that the button is connected to 
  Pushbutton(uint8_t pin, uint8_t pullUp = PULL_UP_ENABLED, 
      uint8_t defaultState = DEFAULT_STATE_HIGH); 

  virtual void init2(); 


protected: 


  virtual bool _isPressed(); 


private: 


   uint8_t _pin; 
   bool _pullUp; 
   bool _defaultState; 
 }; 

 #endif 





// PIN Configurations #define SEARCH_SPEED 255 

#define echoPin A0 
#define triggerPin 3 
#define rightBackMotor 4 
#define rightMotorSpeed 10 
#define leftMotorSpeed 9 
#define leftForwardMotor 7  //if a motor goes backward swap the number on the FwdPin and BckPin 
#define rightForwardMotor 8   //if a motor goes backward swap the number on the FwdPin and BckPin 
#define leftBackMotor 11 
#define LED 13 
#define leftSensor A1 
#define rightSensor A2 
#define IRdriver 6 


// Robot Configuration Parameters 
// Speed range is -255 -> 255 
#define MAX_SPEED 255 
#define QTR_Threshold 500 
#define ATTACK_DISTANCE 25 
#define BACKUP_DISTANCE 4000 
#define SEARCH_SPEED 255


// State variables 
bool isBackup = false; 
int backupTimer = 0; 
long distance = 1000; 
Pushbutton button(ZUMO_BUTTON); 


void setSpeed(int speed, int motor); 


void setup() { 
   Serial.begin(9600); 
   Serial.println("Setup."); 


  pinSetup(); 


   Serial.println("Waiting for button"); 
} 


void loop() { 
   digitalWrite(IRdriver, HIGH); 

  if (button.isPressed()) { 
    // if button is pressed, stop and wait for another press to go again 
    button.waitForRelease(); 
    waitForButtonAndCountDown(); 
 } 


  int leftInput = analogRead(leftSensor); 
  int rightInput = analogRead(rightSensor); 


  if ( isBackup ) { 
    backupTimer = backupTimer + 1; 
    setSpeed(-MAX_SPEED, 0); 
    setSpeed(-MAX_SPEED + 20, 1); 
    if (backupTimer >= BACKUP_DISTANCE ) { 
      isBackup = false; 
      backupTimer = 0; 
    } 
  } else { 
    if ( leftInput <= 500 || rightInput <= 500 ) { // WHITE LINE ABORT! 
      //Serial.println("Abort! - "); Serial.println(leftInput); Serial.println(rightInput); 
      isBackup = true; 
      setSpeed(-MAX_SPEED, 0); 
      setSpeed(-MAX_SPEED, 1); 
    } else { 
      distance = getDistance(); 
      if ( distance <= ATTACK_DISTANCE ) { // ATTACK! 
        Serial.println("Attack!"); 
        setSpeed(MAX_SPEED, 0); 
        setSpeed(MAX_SPEED, 1); 
      } else { // search 
        // TODO(erh): implement other searching algorithms 
        Serial.println("Search");  
        setSpeed(SEARCH_SPEED, 0);
        setSpeed(-SEARCH_SPEED, 1); 
      } 
    } 
  } 
} 


void pinSetup() { 
  // motors! 
  pinMode(leftMotorSpeed, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(rightMotorSpeed, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(leftForwardMotor, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(leftBackMotor, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(rightForwardMotor, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(rightBackMotor, OUTPUT); 

   // sonar sensor 
  pinMode(LED, HIGH); 
  pinMode(triggerPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); 


  // qtr light sensor 
  pinMode(leftSensor, INPUT); 
  pinMode(rightSensor, INPUT); 
  pinMode(IRdriver, OUTPUT); 
} 


void setSpeed(int speed, int motor = 0) { 
  int speedPin, forwardPin, backPin; 
  if ( motor == 0 ) { 
    speedPin = leftMotorSpeed; 
    forwardPin = leftForwardMotor; 
    backPin = leftBackMotor; 
  } else if ( motor == 1 ) { 
    speedPin = rightMotorSpeed; 
    forwardPin = rightForwardMotor; 
    backPin = rightBackMotor; 
  } 


  if ( speed == 0 ) { 
    analogWrite(speedPin, 0); 
    digitalWrite(forwardPin, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(backPin, LOW); 
  } else if ( speed > 0 ) { 
    digitalWrite(forwardPin, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(backPin, LOW); 
    analogWrite(speedPin, speed); 
  } else if ( speed < 0 ) { 
    digitalWrite(forwardPin, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(backPin, HIGH); 
    analogWrite(speedPin, abs(speed)); 
  } 
} 


long getDistance() { 
  long duration, distance; 
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);  // Added this line 
  delayMicroseconds(2); // Added this line 
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH); 
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line 
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW); 
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); 
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1; 
  return distance; 
} 


void waitForButtonAndCountDown() { 
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); 
  button.waitForButton(); 
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW); 


  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) { 
    Serial.println(i); 
    delay(1000); 
  } 


  delay(1000); 
  Serial.println("ATTACK!"); 
  delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: Could you put the error (and code) in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains only the header declarations (`.h` file) for those classes. There should also be another file (probably `.cpp`) that actually implements the code for the classes.

What you pasted looks very similar to the `Pushbutton` stuff in [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/pololu/a-star-32u4-arduino-library).

You can look at their `Pushbutton.h` and `Pushbutton.cpp` files to get an idea of what I mean. In fact, you might be able to use those files instead of what you have. I can verify that it does compile, but not whether it works or not.

Comment: It is the github stuff but I'm new to arduino. Can I take the .cpp file and copy paste the code in because I'm using school computers without much control.

Comment: Ideally you would download the files (e.g. with the "Raw" link when viewing the files) and use them as a library. But yes I think it should also work if you just copy/paste the contents into your project. Just make sure the .h code is above the .cpp code. I had done that and it compiled okay.

Comment: Could you possibly upload your code because I tried to copy paste but I keep getting previous definition of 'class PushbuttonStateMachine'

Comment: I don't have any code saved. I just copied your Pastebin code, deleted the old header stuff (everything between `#ifndef Pushbutton_h` and `#endif`) and pasted in those other two files instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Undefined reference` is a linker error, which means that the Arduino ecosystem is missing some of the pieces for the build. If you have indeed provided `PushButton.cpp` - whether in a library or not - you need to put a `#include` of `Pushbutton.h` inside the `.ino` file. This tells Arduino that you want to include `PushButton`'s code as well as everything else.

If `Pushbutton.cpp` is inside the same directory as the `.ino` file then that will "just work". If it's elsewhere, you need to tell Arduino.